# SQL query help - find table in unknown schema and query data

Tags: sql, oracle, search

I have a couple of simple queries I run manually in Oracle as sysdba to check the version info for a java application. The tricky part is that the schema names vary, so sometimes I have to search for the table to find the owner/schema and then query the info.

Is there a way to take the output from one query and use it to perform a schema-qualified query, so it can be automated?

The queries I use are:

```
SELECT username FROM dba_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'APPVERSDATA%';

SELECT max(appfullversion) from SCHEMA.APPVERSDATA;
```

There must be a way to pass the name of the schema from the first query as a variable to the second query?

Edit: Ultimately I would like to set the output as a variable in shell script.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `SCHEMA.APPVERSDATA` would be the output of the first query so the best thing to do might be execute some PL/SQL as a store function or procedure:

```
DECLARE
  l_schema varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT owner 
  INTO l_schema
  FROM dba_tables
  WHERE table_name LIKE 'APPVERSDATA%';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT max(appfullversion) from ' || l_schema || '.APPVERSDATA';
end;
/
```

This doesn't address what you are going to **do** with the data once it executes though. Update the question and I'll update the answer.
**Edit(Version 2!):**
So your shell would look something like this:

```
x () {
sqlplus -s u/p<<EOF
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;
DECLARE
  l_schema varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT owner 
  INTO l_schema
  FROM dba_tables
  WHERE table_name LIKE 'APPVERSDATA%';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT max(appfullversion) from ' || l_schema || '.APPVERSDATA';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_return);
end;
/
EOF
}
echo $(x $1)
```

Comment: Thx, I updated the question, but I would like to grab the output as a variable in a shell script.